# I cannot print from Okular, however printing from other programs works fine

Tags: okular, xerox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Xerox Phaser 3250. When I try to print from okular, it does not react in any form, however if I print from Kile, evince, libreoffice etc, everything is fine. I hav no any idea, where to look for an answer.